# One machine on network switch seems to be killing network for others - Hacked?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, denial-of-service

I have been trying to setup a new headless Ubuntu server and I have been having all sorts of issues with crashes and server no longer being available. I initially thought that these were hardware issues and that the server was crashing - as the machine is headless when it does not respond to ssh or ping there is not much you can do.

I now believe that this is a networking issue.

### Summary

I have 3 Ubuntu servers all attached to one switch that is attached to a Google Wifi point. They are all mining rigs but I do no think that is relevant.

At random intervals (can be 30 minutes after boot or 9 hours) all 3 of these machines stop responding to pings or ssh requests at the same time.

The rest of my network (on 2 other Google Wifi nodes) is fine and does not seem to be affected at all.

There is a high amount of traffic on the switch connecting the 3 machines (just guessed by observing the lights on the switch).

When I disconnect one of the machines from the switch the other 2 immediately start responding to pings and ssh again, when I re-attach the machine after say 30 seconds they all die again.

### Investigations

Whilst trying to debug what is going on here I have tried various things.

When the network is in this state I am able to ping an address from my laptop that is on wifi, when I then connect that laptop to the affected network switch it is unable to ping anything - the 3 ubuntu machines or anything on the rest of the network.

The only exposure these machines have had to the public internet is having a non-standard port (in the 3000 range) forwarded to port 22 for ssh.

Password access for ssh is turned off and access is only granted via public/private key.

All the machines are newly created over the last week or so and are Ubuntu Server 16. I have not installed much on them at all:

- nano
- nvidia drivers
- mining software (Claymore etherium)
- ssh server
- curl
- tmux
- node

I think that's about it

### What now?

I really don't know where to go with this. I am beginning to suspect that something malicious has got into one of the machines and it is taking part in some DDOS attack or something - by my internet speed did not seem to be affected.

Can anyone suggest what is going on here or how I can about further debugging or solving this issue?

Many Thanks

Comment: Attach to a server's console and inspect the network traffic using `tcpdump`.

Comment: Yes... But I can't attach to the console...

Comment: Why not? What kind of server has neither a video output nor a BMC? How did you _install_ the server without being able to connect a monitor and a keyboard?

Comment: Does "When I disconnect one of the machines" refer to the same machine each time, or does it not matter which machine you disconnect?

Comment: @grawity - the server has all monitor output disabled as all the GPUs are used for mining. To enable overclocking of the card you need to convince the nvidia driver that it has a monitor attached to each card so you generate fake monitors - so a real monitor has no output at all.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - I think that it has to be a certain machine each time it happens but different machines have had the issue so the machine I have to disconnect varies.
All the machines are basically identical so it makes sense that any of them could go mental.

Comment: Then set up a serial console. Many servers have a serial port, and a serial-to-USB adapter is very cheap.

Comment: @Roaders Can you try a different Ethernet switch and/or cables? Is it a managed switch so that you could mirror port traffic to a machine running [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) - if you feel like looking at the network traffic to see if anything stands out.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - It's a pretty basic netgear switch. Nothing fancy like that. I am pretty sure that this happened when I had 2 machines connected directly to the Google Wifi rather than connected to a switch.
I can try different cables and try removing the switch.

Comment: @Roaders With the equipment you have available, it looks like grawity's suggestion to set up a serial console is going to be the easiest way to access the Ubuntu machines and find out what is going on.